Why is my implentation of an hover effect in html not working?
I am trying to implement an hover effect on a table in a webpage so when I put my mouse on the row the row turns grey but everything else is white
So I have the basic styling just to ensure that its not my workplace thats bugged and well it works now when I implement it in the bigger code, nothing happens. I am new to working with CSS so I have no idea how to fix this. I was wondering if it is because I set the entire table container to white but how do i set the table to white but still implement the hover effect without them both affecting each other.
This is my implementation


.specific-table-container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.specific-table-container table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.specific-table-container th,
.specific-table-container td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.specific-table-container tr:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
<div class="specific-table-container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>{text}</td>
        <th>List</th>
        <td>{list:label}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>
          <p>{text}</p>
        </td>
        <th>List</th>
        <td>{list:label}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Hover Test</title>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        tr:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;  /* Grey color on hover */
        }
    </style>


since you have your rules where the :hover acts on <tr> (rows) you may just set the default colour on rows instead of cells (td). So the point is having background set to white on a rule targeting tr also when it's not on :hover (and remove any rule setting the background on td). In short, in your latest css just add tr{background: white;}

Your td's have a background-color as well, which overrules the background color for the tr's
If you want to make the whole table white and have a hover effect for the rows, consider only styling the tr, not the td.
In the example below I removed the background-color: #fff; for the th and td


.specific-table-container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.specific-table-container table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.specific-table-container th,
.specific-table-container td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

.specific-table-container tr:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
<div class="specific-table-container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>{text}</td>
        <th>List</th>
        <td>{list:label}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>
          <p>{text}</p>
        </td>
        <th>List</th>
        <td>{list:label}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



